# How to set a color of a hotspot region on image map

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, imagemap

I have dynamically created a hotspot region and i want to change the color of this hotspot region how can i achieve this? i also want to show the border of the hotspot region.

Here is my code to create a hotspot on a image map in c# dynamically

```
protected void txtall_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = txtall.Text.Split(',');
//create hotspot once there are 10 cordinates
    if (arr.Length == 10)
    {
        PolygonHotSpot Polygon1 = new PolygonHotSpot();
        Polygon1.Coordinates = arr[0].ToString() + "," + arr[1].ToString() + "," + arr[2].ToString() + "," + arr[3].ToString()
            + "," + arr[4].ToString() + "," + arr[5].ToString() + "," + arr[6].ToString() + "," + arr[7].ToString() + "," + arr[8].ToString() + "," + arr[9].ToString();// "128,185,335,157,400,224,400,400,228,400";

        Polygon1.NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com";
        Polygon1.AlternateText = "Southern Region";

        ImageMap1.HotSpots.Add(Polygon1);
    }
}
```

I have tried to use the jquery from [here](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) but i am not able to succeed. I am absolutely new to jquery, i simply copy pasted the jquery function and added reference but it did not work for me.i am nt shwing up js code as it is simply copy paste from the above link.Can anyone provide a simple style or any java/jquery function so dat i can see an effect on the hotspot region?

Kindly help.thank You.

**UPDATE:**
*JAVASCRIPT*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JScript.js"></script>
    //
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function point_it(event) {
            pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
            pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
            document.getElementById("ImageMap1").style.left = (pos_x - 1);
            document.getElementById("ImageMap1").style.top = (pos_y - 15);

            document.getElementById("txt1").value = pos_x;
            document.getElementById("txt2").value = pos_y;
            if (document.getElementById("txtall").value == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtall").value = pos_x + "," + pos_y;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("txtall").value = document.getElementById("txtall").value + "," + pos_x + "," + pos_y;
            }
            var str = document.getElementById("txtall").value;
            var stringArray = new Array();
            stringArray = str.split(",");
            for (i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                stringArray[i];
            }
            if (i == 10) {
            //Creates Hotspot Dynamically
                __doPostBack('txtall ', '');

                //Effects to be applied for the hotspot created
                  var image = $('#ImageMap1');

    image.mapster(
    {
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        fillColor: "d42e16",
        stroke: true,
        strokeColor: "3320FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWidth: 4,
        singleSelect: true,
        mapKey: 'name',
        listKey: 'name',

        areas: [
            {
                fillColor: "ffffff"
            },

            ]
    });​
            }
            //Clears hotspot
            if (i >= 10) {
                __doPostBack('txtall ', '');
                str = "";
                i = 0;
                stringArray = [];
            }
        }
    </script>
```

*ASPX*

```
<form name="pointform" runat="server">
    <div id="pointer_div" onclick="point_it(event)" style="width: 500px; height: 333px;">
        <asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/WMap.JPG" Style="width: 500px;
            height: 333px;">
        </asp:ImageMap>
    </div>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtall" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtall_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
```

If i put the jquery `image.mapster` than i get the exception as `point_it(event)` is undefined.. code works fine if i remove the jqery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and edited it. It now **does a postback on txtall has 10 coordinates**. *Afterwards* there is a **postBack** and *then you see your colored area!*

**ScriptCode**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/imageMapster/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var image = $('#ImageMap1');
        image.mapster({
            fillOpacity: 0.4,
            fillColor: "d42e16",
            stroke: true,
            strokeColor: "3320FF",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWidth: 4,
            singleSelect: true,
            mapKey: 'shape',
            listKey: 'shape'
        });

        $("#pointer_div").click(function(event) {
            pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
            pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
            document.getElementById("ImageMap1").style.left = (pos_x - 1);
            document.getElementById("ImageMap1").style.top = (pos_y - 15);

            document.getElementById("txt1").value = pos_x;
            document.getElementById("txt2").value = pos_y;
            if (document.getElementById("txtall").value == "") 
                document.getElementById("txtall").value = pos_x + "," + pos_y;
            else 
                document.getElementById("txtall").value = document.getElementById("txtall").value + "," + pos_x + "," + pos_y;

             var str = document.getElementById("txtall").value;
             var stringArray = new Array();
             stringArray = str.split(",");
             for (i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                stringArray[i];
            }
            if (i == 10) 
            {
                __doPostBack('txtall ', '');

            }
            //Clears hotspot
            if (i >= 10) {
                __doPostBack('txtall ', '');
                str = "";
                i = 0;
                stringArray = [];
            }
        });
    });                
</script>
```

**ASPX Code**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div id="pointer_div" style="width: 500px; height: 333px;">
        <asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server" ImageUrl="pic/usa_map_720.png" Style="width: 500px;
            height: 333px;">
        </asp:ImageMap>
    </div>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtall" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtall_TextChanged" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void txtall_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = txtall.Text.Split(',');
    //create hotspot once there are 10 cordinates
    if (arr.Length == 10)
    {
        PolygonHotSpot Polygon1 = new PolygonHotSpot();
        Polygon1.Coordinates = arr[0].ToString() + "," + arr[1].ToString() + "," + arr[2].ToString() + "," + arr[3].ToString()
            + "," + arr[4].ToString() + "," + arr[5].ToString() + "," + arr[6].ToString() + "," + arr[7].ToString() + "," + arr[8].ToString() + "," + arr[9].ToString();// "128,185,335,157,400,224,400,400,228,400";

        Polygon1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        Polygon1.AlternateText = "Southern Region";

        ImageMap1.HotSpots.Add(Polygon1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any JQuery plugin for this.

one found [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/image-scripts/highlight-image-map-area-hotspots-jquery/#.UFg7W7Lib8o)